# android-instant-apps can't be launched for some minutes after download completely

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I click the url for my instant-app, google play store launched and ask me open it in browser or app, I click app, and it start download my instant app, after download completely it not launcher my instant app but launched chrome browser, after some minutes, when I click the url again it launched my instant app.

I want to know how to make it launcher my instant app directly after download finish. I think maybe android system is verify the json file, so it launched chrome and after verification finish and click url again it launcher instant app, but not very sure.

If anyone knows the reason or has encountered this problem, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you happen to grab a logcat when it redirected to Chrome?

Comment: @JichaoLi No, I try to get the logcat a moment ago, but work fine. It's not happened every time.

Comment: Let’s first double check your JSON file to rule that out: https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator. Also, the asynchronous verification can take some time to process (~20 sec) before linking your app/instant-app.

Comment: @TWL Ok, thanks, my JSON file is right, I also think it's a network problem.

Comment: This will happen if your instant app crashes while trying to launch (to prevent the user from having a broken experience). As Jichao and others mentioned, the best thing is to look through your logcat and see what might have gone wrong.

Comment: @ijustyce , hope your problems has been solved.